# Altair Stripplot - bring columns together

Tags: python, altair

with this dataframe structure, `df_ppp`:

```
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   MeanPPP       628 non-null    object
 1   StdPPP        626 non-null    object
 2   MeanPPG       628 non-null    object
 3   MeanPrice     628 non-null    object
 4   MeanSelected  628 non-null    object
 5   TotalMinutes  628 non-null    object
 6   TotalPoints   628 non-null    object
 7   Position      628 non-null    object
 8   Team          628 non-null    object
 9   Player        628 non-null    object
 10  Color         628 non-null    object
```

and the following code:

```
stripplot =  alt.Chart(df_ppp, width=120).mark_circle().encode(
      x=alt.X(
          'jitter:Q',
          title=None,
          axis=alt.Axis(values=[0], ticks=True, grid=False, labels=False),
          scale=alt.Scale(),
      ),
      y=alt.Y('MeanPPP:Q'),
      color=alt.Color('Color:N', legend=None, scale=None),
      tooltip = [alt.Tooltip('Player:N'),
                alt.Tooltip('Position:N'),
                alt.Tooltip('Team:N'),
                alt.Tooltip('MeanPPP:Q'),
                alt.Tooltip('MeanPPG:Q'),
                alt.Tooltip('MeanPrice:Q'),
                alt.Tooltip('MeanSelected:Q'),
                alt.Tooltip('TotalMinutes:Q'),
                alt.Tooltip('TotalPoints:Q')],
      column=alt.Column(
          'Team:N',
          header=alt.Header(
              labelAngle=-90,
              titleOrient='top',
              labelOrient='bottom',
              labelAlign='right',
              labelPadding=10,
          ),
      ),
  ).transform_calculate(
      # Generate Gaussian jitter with a Box-Muller transform
      jitter='sqrt(-2*log(random()))*cos(2*PI*random())'
  ).configure_facet(
      spacing=0
  ).configure_view(
      stroke=None
  ).configure_axis(
        grid=False
  ).properties(height=300, width=50)
```

I'm plotting this:

[image]

---

This is the result I'm aiming at, with stripplots closer to each value.

[Altair examples - stripplot](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/stripplot.html)

[image]

---

How do I bring the columns closer togeher?

Comment: You're encoding x and y as two values that are correlated within your dataset, causing them to appear as a line. If you want the points on your chart to not be correlated, you should use data that is not correlated

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it. how do I uncorrelate the data?

Comment: @jakevdp I had the wrong column as X, now it is the correct one, 'Team'. now how do I join those points closer together and improved jitter effect?

Comment: @jakevdp I've edited the question with new plotted image.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're seeing. Without full code that reproduces your chart, you are unlikely to get any useful answer to your question.

Comment: @jakevdp I've figured it out. please refer to answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Altair code was perfect.

The problem with column width did not belong to `altair`, but to `streamlit` config, which is being used to plot `altair` charts.

`streamlit` was overriding column width.

So I've changed:

```
st.altair_chart(stripplot, use_container_width=True)
```

to:

```
st.altair_chart(stripplot)
```

and now I plot:

[image]